# How to get result from an awaitble method in non async method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, async-await

In NTT Framework and MVC 5 web application, I sometimes want to call an awaitable method from a non asynchronous method like this:

```
private List<DormObject> GetAllActiveDorms()
    {
        using (ApplicationDbContext Db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            return Db.Dorms
                .Select( d => new DormObject
                {
                    ID = d.ID,
                    Name = d.Name,
                    Address = d.Address,
                    AdminName = (await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(d.AdminID)).UserName,
                    Gender = d.Gender
                }).ToList() ?? new List<DormObject> { };
        }
    }
```

and this way is imposible! also this async method is called in lambda expression!

How can I receive the 'UserName' value?

Comment: You can use `.Result`

Comment: How can i use? where?

Comment: in lambda expression its not working!

Comment: `UserManager.FindByIdAsync(d.AdminID).Result` without the `await`

Comment: @Yacoub: But that's exposing the code to a deadlock.

Comment: Is `GetAllActiveDorms` running from the UI thread?

Comment: its called from a controller

Comment: You can't just call `Result` on an async method. As @sstan says, you're exposing your code to deadlocks and all other sort of nastiness. In EF 6, all the sync methods just call the async versions and the EF came up with a helper class to run async as sync. If it's good enough for them, it should be good enough for your project to. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28682183/654031

Comment: @ChrisPratt Thanks! I've Read it!
a question: Is the Helper class must be 'static'?

Comment: "Must"? No. Should be? Yes. Otherwise, you'd need to instantiate it to use it each time, and you end up with useless copies of it all over the place in memory. It has no data of its own, so a static class is the appropriate choice.

Comment: still not working! here is the exception:
'An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Models.AppUser RunSync[AppUser](System.Func`1[System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Models.AppUser]])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'

Comment: Try moving the UserManager.FindByIdAsync(d.AdminID).Result.UserName to a variable.

Comment: This isn't the answer, so just a comment, but I'd suggest you *try to not do that* at all.  I.e. don't put data that belongs to one entity (User) inside another entity (Dorm) in your domain model.  Just put the AdminId in there instead.  If the calling code needs a name, it can use the UserManager to load the user and get one that way.